# Failed to start bitcoin daemon using Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu

Hey I keep getting this error everytime I run sudo systemctl enable --now bitcoind

Job for bitcoind.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status bitcoind.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I input sudo journalctl -xe --unit bitcoind I get this:

```
bitcoind.service - Bitcoin daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service; enabled; vendor pres>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-12-30 15:12:05 UTC; 23s >
    Process: 2411 ExecStartPre=/bin/chgrp admin /etc/bitcoin (code=exited, stat>
```

Here is how my bitcoind.service looks. I changed the user and group from bitcoin to admin.

```
[Unit]
Description=Bitcoin daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bitcoind -daemon \
                            -pid=/run/bitcoind/bitcoind.pid \
                            -conf=/etc/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf \
                            -datadir=/var/lib/bitcoind

# Make sure the config directory is readable by the service user
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/chgrp admin /etc/bitcoin

# Process management
####################

Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/bitcoind/bitcoind.pid
Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStopSec=600

# Run as admin:admin
User=admin
Group=admin

# /run/bitcoind
RuntimeDirectory=bitcoind
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0710

# /etc/bitcoin
ConfigurationDirectory=bitcoin
ConfigurationDirectoryMode=0710

# /var/lib/bitcoind
StateDirectory=bitcoind
StateDirectoryMode=0710

# Hardening measures
####################
# Provide a private /tmp and /var/tmp.
PrivateTmp=true

# Deny access to /home, /root and /run/user
ProtectHome=true

# Mount /usr, /boot/ and /etc read-only for the process.
ProtectSystem=full

# Disallow the process and all of its children to gain
# new privileges through execve().
NoNewPrivileges=true

# Use a new /dev namespace only populated with API pseudo devices
# such as /dev/null, /dev/zero and /dev/random.
PrivateDevices=true

# Deny the creation of writable and executable memory mappings.
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here are the steps I made before:

```
~$ cd src
~/src$ git clone --depth 1 --branch v0.20.1 https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
~/src$ cd bitcoin
~/src/bitcoin$ ./contrib/install_db4.sh `pwd`
~/src/bitcoin$ ./autogen.sh
~/src/bitcoin$ export BDB_PREFIX='/home/ubuntu/src/bitcoin/db4'
~/src/bitcoin$ ./configure BDB_LIBS="-L${BDB_PREFIX}/lib -ldb_cxx-4.8" BDB_CFLAGS="-I${BDB_PREFIX}/include"
~/src/bitcoin$ make
~/src/bitcoin$ sudo make install 
~/src/bitcoin$ bitcoind -version
vi bitcoin.conf
server=1                              
rpcbind=127.0.0.1                     
whitelist=127.0.0.1                   
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1/32               
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332  
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333 

~$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/bitcoin
~$ sudo cp bitcoin.conf /etc/bitcoin
~$ sudo chmod 644 /etc/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

Utimately I got

> ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Bitcoin daemon.

Comment: I think this would better be addressed in the Bitcoin Core issue tracker and I see you've opened an issue. Hence probably best to close this StackExchange question https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20818

Answer (score 0):

if you installed Bitcoin core using a PPA, it means your script is looking for bitcoind in the wrong place.

To confirm where your bitcoind was installed, use `whereis bitcoind`

This will likely return `/usr/local/bin/bitcoind`, now your script is looking for it in `/usr/bin/bitcoind` so you can either copy it into that directory

`sudo cp /usr/local/bin/bitcoind /usr/bin/bitcoind`

or change your script to look for it in `/usr/local/bin/bitcoind`